# I used cursor_loop: loop in sql stored procedure its not fetching all 15 rows it fetch one row only

Tags: java, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

Here it is mycode for fetch 15 rows in the cursor..But its fetching one row not fetching 15 rows any error in this code.any help would be appreciated .Thanks in advance

```
delimiter $$

drop procedure if exists retrieve_relstr_roc_price;

create procedure retrieve_relstr_roc_price(
   in  p_begin_date      datetime
)
begin

  declare no_more_rows     boolean;
  declare l_symbol         varchar(10);
  declare l_commit_rows    int default 60;
 declare l_row_num        int default 0;

 declare roc_value_cursor cursor for
       select * from(select distinct(symbol) as symbol from 
eqt_price_ta_relstr where category_name in ((select * from (select 
sn.category_name  from eqt_price_ta_relstr ept 
inner join sectornames sn on sn.symbol = ept.symbol where ept.category_name 
= "SPsector" and ept.close_date >= p_begin_date group by sn.category_name  order by ept.rank5 limit 0,1 )  t4  )) and close_date >= p_begin_date group by symbol  order by rank5 limit 15) as t1;     
   declare continue handler for not found set no_more_rows = true;


   open roc_value_cursor;
  cursor_loop: loop
  fetch roc_value_cursor
  into  l_symbol;
  if no_more_rows
  then
     close roc_value_cursor;
     leave cursor_loop;
  end if;

/*next part code used the cursor value*/
```

Comment: Use a column name instead of * because the receiving variables is only one.

Comment: I have tried by using column name but still fetching one row.

Comment: Does the cursor query actually return 15 tuples?.

Comment: Yes its returning 15 rows @wchiquito

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t1`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t1` (
    ->   `symbol` VARCHAR(10) 
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `t1`
    -> VALUES ('symbol 1'), ('symbol 2'),
    ->        ('symbol 3'), ('symbol 4'),
    ->        ('symbol 5'), ('symbol 6'),
    ->        ('symbol 7'), ('symbol 8'),
    ->        ('symbol 9'), ('symbol 10'),
    ->        ('symbol 11'), ('symbol 12'),
    ->        ('symbol 13'), ('symbol 14'),
    ->        ('symbol 15');
Query OK, 15 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 15  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `retrieve_relstr_roc_price`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `retrieve_relstr_roc_price`()
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `no_more_rows` BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
    ->   DECLARE `l_symbol` VARCHAR(10);
    ->   DECLARE `l_row_num` INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    ->   DECLARE `roc_value_cursor` CURSOR FOR
    ->   SELECT * -- It's recommended to identify the columns: SELECT `symbol` ...
    ->   FROM (
    ->         SELECT `symbol`
    ->         FROM `t1`
    ->        ) `der`;
    ->   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET `no_more_rows` := TRUE;
    ->   OPEN `roc_value_cursor`;
    ->   `cursor_loop`: LOOP
    ->     FETCH `roc_value_cursor` INTO `l_symbol`;
    ->     IF `no_more_rows` THEN
    ->       CLOSE `roc_value_cursor`;
    ->       LEAVE `cursor_loop`;
    ->     END IF;
    ->     SET `l_row_num` := `l_row_num` + 1;
    ->   END LOOP `cursor_loop`;
    ->   SELECT `l_row_num`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `retrieve_relstr_roc_price`;
+-------------+
| `l_row_num` |
+-------------+
|          15 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nmTYnmySHhdRyaS3jZYA7t/0).